# Is F# open source?

Tags: open-source, f#

Is F# open source? if not so why Microsoft provide the source code of the F#'s modules?

EDIT

(Nov 4, 2010) Things have changed, see [Brian McKenna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575521/is-f-open-source/4103116#4103116).

Comment: For some reason this feels like a plug for a (not spell-checked) blog...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an external business's decision that could change at any time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now the F# team seems pretty busy with all the "productisation" effort. One email with the plans for the licensing is [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.fsharp.general/1000).

> As we complete this over the next year, our plan is to make a
>   corresponding source release of the F#
>   compiler components under MS-PL.

And:

> Along the way, we plan to make a
>   source release of the MSR "Power Pack"
>   components, also under MS-PL. These
>   include tools such as fslex.exe and
>   fsyacc.exe and some libraries. These
>   may be released more often and may
>   include experimental components.

With:

> In general, we aim for the source code
>   releases we make of F# to open, stable
>   and correspond to supported releases.

And perhaps the nicest bit :) :

> On the whole we prefer to "do" rather
>   than "pre-announce".

I'll also note that if you're not using the term "Open Source" meaning "approved by certain organisations as Open Source", then the source code is already included with the F# distro. (And using F12 "Go To Definition" in VS will jump you right to the source files.)

Comment: I far as I understand, there's no point. I consider it to be just a marketing trick. If someone knows better, please explain.

Comment: Having the source to the F# system is incredibly valuable, even if it's not "Open Source" (although the MS-PL is OSI accepted.) 1. Researchers can do work with the F# code (I dream of macros and dependent types). 2. Having the library code has been invaluable for learning.

Comment: Ok, I agree with the point that having lots of well-written code (libraries) available is beneficial for learning a new language. Luckily we all have the autonomous right to decide which languages to learn. Not being open source means automatic decline for many of us.

Comment: @dotnet_1: answer to your question: supplying the source code is necessary but not sufficient for open source. You must also supply a license that allows the rest of the world to do something with the source. Then we're talking about real open source, not merely "shared source".

Comment: mad-j sorry to hear you are under such restrictions :(.

Comment: Well I'm not that sorry - there are so many excellent open source languages available that it's hard to decide which one to learn next. It's good to have even some restrictions.

Answer (score 12):

As of November 2010, the F# compiler and library are being released under the [Apache license](https://www.apache.org/licenses/). They are now part of the [F# PowerPack](https://web.archive.org/web/20180123010617/http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com:80/).

You can read more from the [blog post announcing it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsyme/announcing-the-f-compiler-library-source-code-drop).

Comment: Best news I've heard this week. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 5):

"Microsoft Research Shared Source license", under which F# is published, has **not** been approved by Open Source Initiative nor by Free Software Foundation (although a [couple of other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_source) Microsoft licenses are).

The bottom line is that sharing the source code has little to do with making a product open source. The essential point is the license, which (dis)allows to use and modify the source more or less freely. Without such a license the source is pretty much useless.

Comment: Which is irrelevant now, since F# has been released under the Apache License.

Comment: That's a Good Thing(tm). I just wonder why they didn't release it under a decent license in the first place. How did anybody benefit from those couple of years under that goofy MRSS license?

Answer (score 4):

It is published under a variant of the MS-Research [open source licence](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/0/2/a02725c2-4eb7-45e1-8e13-24d3c1141115/LICENSE-fsharp.txt).

I have no idea if this is "officially" open.

Answer (score 2):

f# as of the 2008 CTP release is under a slightly modified [Microsoft Research Shared Source license agreement](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/0/2/a02725c2-4eb7-45e1-8e13-24d3c1141115/LICENSE-fsharp.txt)  ("MSR-SSLA").

Essentially you can modify it but MS gets royalty free permission all your modifications

There was talk within the team of it moving to the more open MS-PL licence, I don't know how that has gone, nor what the implications are given the plan to include f# in VS2010.

Comment: not sure what the -1 is for? care to let me know...

Comment: No worries - just wondered if I had put something incorrect down, if it was you it would show you a yellow high light on the down arrow so wouldn't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Did anybody actually try to build F# from the sources included in the release? It seems to me that some parts are missing which prevent this. This is in addition to a license which is not OSI-approved. So, no, F# is not open source.