# Are there any F# alternative (non-.Net) implementation projects?

Tags: f#

Some popular languages like Python and Ruby have native, JVM and .Net CLR implementations. C# is implemented with free Mono project. Aren't there any attempts of implementing F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a compiler for targeting a subset of F# to FPGAs, which I guess is a non-.NET implementation

http://www.avalda.com/

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsyme/from-parallel-f-to-parallel-fpgas-from-avalda)

Comment: As far as I know, this actually uses F# quotations under the cover (so it is still standard .NET version of F# compiler). However, if that counts as an "alternative implementation" then it is also worth mentioning WebSharper (http://www.intellifactory.com/) which compiles F# (quotations) to JavaScript.

Answer (score 9):

As others pointed out, the standard F# implementation from Microsoft is just a .NET (CLI) application that runs on multiple implementations of CLI (namely .NET and Mono). F# also produces .NET (CLI) applications as libraries that also work on both .NET and Mono. However, that is still the same *CLI implementation* of F# (just running on different implementation of CLI)

**To answer your question -**

- As far as I know, there is no other attempt to implement F# compiler for other platforms/runtimes.
- F# shares a common background with [OCaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/), so the easiest way to get another implementation of F# would be to take OCaml and add F#-specific features (and remove OCaml-specific features).
- You can use only shared sub-language and cross-compile using both F# and OCaml.

Also, there are some plans [to release F# as open source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575521/is-f-open-source), so it may be possible that (in the future), someone will port F# to other platforms such as JVM using the source (when released).

Comment: For what its worth, I've seen some camlp4 macros for Ocaml which implement active patterns, computation expressions, and use of whitespace for block level scope. With some degree of macro hacking, you could write OCaml with an F# syntax.

Comment: Are the Camlp macros open sourced?

Answer (score 8):

F# interactive, fsi.exe, already runs on Mono, as do compiled F# programs.

Comment: F# compiler runs on Mono as well, but that's still .NET implementation of F# (just running on Mono)

Answer (score 3):

Mono is an implementation of *.net* which happens to include a c# compiler (as well as a vb compiler). It is not primarily a c# implementation.