# What license does F# 2.0 (2010) use?

Tags: f#, licensing

Is F# 2.0, released in 2010, still under the Microsoft Research Shared Source License Agreement?  I know [this question was asked for F# version 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575521/is-f-open-source), but I got the feeling that things might change with F# 2.0.

Is this license considered free and/or open?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, still is [see here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f8c623ae-aef6-4a06-a185-05f59be47d67&displaylang=en) specifically [this link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/8/7/A870FF76-A9A5-426C-9BF3-9A6300A8A785/LICENSE-fsharp.txt)

Microsoft Research Shared Source License Agreement
(NON-STANDARD FOR F# Compiler)
<

Of course, parts of the .Net libraries aren't covered.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the license link at first.

Answer (score 4):

[As of 2010-11-04](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/11/04/announcing-the-f-compiler-library-source-code-drop.aspx), the F# compiler and standard library are available from Microsoft under the Apache 2.0 license. [The FSF considers this license free and compatible with the GPLv3.](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#apache2)

The code is also available as [a Github project](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp), under [the same license](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/LICENSE).

Answer (score 3):

(IANAL)

I think the short answer is

- There are bits that ship with VS2010 (e.g. compiler, IDE, ...).  They're subject to the VS2010 license, which is presumably somewhat restrictive.
- There is the F# Runtime (FSharp.Core.dll), which is a redistributable package.  You can e.g. chain it into the install/setup of your own app.
- There is the F# CTP.  It essentially contains the same bits as the VS release, minus the VS IDE support.  It also has source code.  It's under the MS Research license, which is less restrictive.
- There is the PowerPack, a library with source, I forget what license it has.
- In the future, there may be an open-source release of the compiler, which would be like the CTP, but with an even more permissive license (the kind of license the FSF folks like).

In general, with each download, there should be an accompanying license which you can read.

EDIT

(November 4, 2010) Now the F# compiler/runtime source is available under the Apache license, see here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/11/04/announcing-the-f-compiler-library-source-code-drop.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Other people answered with regard to the current license.  I'll note that it is neither free nor open as defined by the FSF and OSI.  Among other things, it has serious non-commercial restrictions.  E.g. you can't distribute source code for commercial purposes.

There are only two free Microsoft licenses, the Microsoft Public License and Microsoft Reciprocal License.

Comment: I believe that the non-commerical part is not true, but the FSF/OSI part is true.

Comment: @Brian, it explicitly says, "You may not use or distribute this Software or any derivative works in any form for 
commercial purposes, except as follows"  The exceptions are minor and do not apply to the source code.

Comment: F# uses a modified SSLA that's slightly less chilly towards commercial software. You're allowed to *use* the software for commercial purposes, you're just not allowed to *distribute* it commercially. So you can charge for an F# application (and even include the F# libraries with it), but you can't charge for F# itself. So it's still not Free Software, but it's free enough for most people's purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a license link on the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f8c623ae-aef6-4a06-a185-05f59be47d67&displaylang=en). Still under the SSLA.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the license link at first.